# Intellisense not working with CMake FetchContent

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, intellisense

I am new to CMake and have been playing around with a "Modern CMake" approach.
A brief overview of the project structure:

```
+ project folder
    - CMakeList
    + src
        - CMakeList
        - lib.cpp
    + tests
        - CMakeList
        - test.cpp
```

I have two issues that I would like to address. The main one is getting Intellisense to show code option and colorize the text within test.cpp.

my tests CMakeList

```
# CMakeList for the tests folder

include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
  googletest
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/google/googletest.git
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)

# this helps remove the MSVCRTD warning
add_definitions(-DNODEFAULTLIB:MSVCRTD)

# this helps remove a bunch of static vs dynamic erros
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "/MTd")

add_executable(set1_solu_tests tests.cpp)
target_link_libraries(set1_solu_tests GTest::gtest GTest::gtest_main set1_solu_lib)
add_test(NAME TwoSumTests COMMAND set1_solu_tests)
```

Everything compiles and can run, however, Intellisense does not work only in test.cpp. Even std::vector is not colorized.

code within google test not colorized:

```
TEST(TwoSum, set1)
{
    int t = 17;
    std::vector<int> nums{ 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11, 12, 17, 16, 20, 10 };
    auto result = twoSum(nums, t);

    std::vector<int> a{ 4, 11 };
    std::vector<int> b{ 11, 4 };
    EXPECT_TRUE(result == a || result == b);
}
```

I would like to keep it short if possible and add external project seem very long and complicated.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot where it's not colorized. It's unclear what you mean exactly.

Comment: https://imgur.com/gallery/Qo5Hk04
auto and int are colorized but vector or any kind of auto fill does not work.

Comment: still not clear  what the problem is in the image.  also, in CMakeSettings.json, there are options to specify intellisense operation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/cmakesettings-reference?view=msvc-160

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite strange and in my side, the `vector` is colored by your provided code.

[image]

So please make sure that you have added `add_subdirectory ("CMakeList")` under `CMakeLists.txt` file. And make sure that there is no error for your project.

Or you could try this:

**One)** disable any third party installed extensions under **Extensions**-->**Manage Extensions**. When you finish this, you should restart VS.

**Two)** close VS, delete `.vs` hidden folder under the solution folder, also the `out` folder.

Then, restart your VS, open your CMake project to test again.

**Besides**, if this does not work, please check this:

First, delete the content of your `tests CMakeList` from `CMakeLists.txt` file, rebuild cmake project. Then, close VS, try the **above step two** option. After that, restart VS, your cmake project, re-add the content of your `tests CMakeList` into `CMakeLists.txt` file.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I ended up updating my extensions then recreate my CMakeList.txt one line at a time and eventually got it to work again.

Comment: Same issue here. I think this just doesn't work well out of the box, needs another pass from DevEx point of view. For example, I have this dependency in the project and VS won't download it, intellisense is clueless about it: https://github.com/madmann91/bvh